# Executing multiple statements with Postgresql via SQLAlchemy does not persist changes

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

This does not work – the update has no effect:

```
command = "select content from blog where slug = 'meow'; update account_balance set balance=200 where id=1; select 1 from blog;"
content = db.engine.scalar(command)
```

Switching the statements performs the update and select successfully:

```
command = "update account_balance set balance=200 where id=1; select content from blog where slug = 'meow';"
content = db.engine.scalar(command)
```

Why does the first not work? It works in Pgadmin. I enabled autocommit with Flask-Sqlalchemy.

I am doing a workshop on SQL injection, so please dont rewrite the solution!

Comment: Define "doesn't work"? Exactly.

Comment: @CraigRinger the account_balance row doesn't update, of course

Comment: @IljaEverilä, I get no error since the db executes them, but the update statement has no effect

Comment: @IljaEverilä You are right. I forgot to include something to avoid the error. And I use 1.1.12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way SQLAlchemy's autocommit works is that it inspects the issued statements, trying to [detect whether or not data is modified](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit):

> ..., SQLAlchemy implements its own “autocommit” feature which works completely consistently across all backends. This is achieved by detecting statements which represent data-changing operations, i.e. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, as well as data definition language (DDL) statements such as CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, and then issuing a COMMIT automatically if no transaction is in progress. The detection is based on the presence of the `autocommit=True` execution option on the statement. If the statement is a text-only statement and the flag is not set, a regular expression is used to detect INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, as well as a variety of other commands for a particular backend

Since [multiple result sets are not supported](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#multiple-result-sets) at SQLAlchemy level, in your first example the detection simply omits issuing a COMMIT because the *first* statement is a SELECT, where as in your second example it is an UPDATE. No attempt to detect data modifying statements from multiple statements takes place.

If you look at [`PGExecutionContext.should_autocommit_text()`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py#L2034), you'll see that it does a [regex match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match) against [`AUTOCOMMIT_REGEXP`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py#L892). In other words it matches only at the beginning of the text.

Comment: I appended a `commit` and now it works. SQLAlchemy must have forgotten to issue it by itself. Is your speculation that SQLA checks the *last* statement for whether it should issue a commit?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the answer. It is the *first* statement that matters (like in your second example, where the first statement is the UPDATE). Also added some context as to why.

Comment: Wow seriously? That's an insane way to implement that. Don't use that feature!

Comment: @craig-ringer It works ok for single textual SQL statements, and if you really want both multi-statement SQL strings (which SQLA does not seem to officially support, but leaves for DBAPI level) and autocommit, there's `text(...).execution_options(autocommit=True)`, as documented in ["Understanding Autocommit"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit), though I guess that's more commonly used for signalling that a function or SP mutates data and should commit. On the other hand personally I'm not a fan of autocommit in general.

Comment: Wouldn't it fail hopelessly with `SELECT insert_something(...)`?

Comment: @CraigRinger Absolutely. That's why the docs have the example `engine.execute(text("SELECT my_mutating_procedure()").execution_options(autocommit=True))`. I actually ran in to similar issues before support for REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW was added. Had to manually mark the session as dirty so that the transaction context handler would issue a COMMIT.

Comment: @CraigRinger SQLAlchemy specifically isn't an SQL *parser* - but completely the opposite. It is a screwdriver with a small hammer on top... now if you have lots of nails, use another tool.

Comment: So in other words it does't try to be correct for the general case or fail gracefully? You must know its limitations and work within them. Right? (Note, I use PostgreSQL but not SQLAlchemy so outside perspective)

Comment: @CraigRinger Regarding the autocommit feature, and running textual SQL, yeah. But you'd usually not use much SQL text, unless you've a lot of existing more or less complex queries that you want to run. The Pythonic query builder/compiler, either using Core or the ORM, is the thing you want SQLAlchemy for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a table using `SELECT INTO`:

As explained above `engine.execute('select * into a from b')` doesn't work. Instead you can do as follows:

```py
conn = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('select * into a from b')
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `db.engine.execute(...).first()` if you want to execute everything and get only first row.