# Calling stored function or procedure won't insert and persist changes

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

So I am very confused about this weird behaviour I have with SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL. Let's say I have a table:

```
create table staging.my_table( 
  id integer DEFAULT nextval(...),
  name text,
  ...
);
```

and a stored function:

```
create or replace function staging.test()
  returns void
  language plpgsql
  as $function$
begin    
   insert into staging.my_table (name) values ('yay insert');
end;
$function$;
```

What I want to do now is call this function in Python with SQLAlchemy like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://foo:bar@localhost:5432/baz')
engine.execute('select staging.test()')
```

---

When I run this Python code nothing get's inserted in my database. That's weird because when I replace the function call with `select 1` and add `.fetchall()` to it it gets executed and I see the result in console when I print it.

Let's say I run this code twice and nothing happens but code runs successful without errors.
If I switch to the database now and run `select staging.test();` and select my_table I get: `id: 3; name: yay insert`.

So that means the sequence **is actually increasing** when I run my Python file but there is **no data** in my table.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? I googled but didn't find anything.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347565/executing-multiple-statements-with-postgresql-via-sqlalchemy-does-not-persist-ch. Autocommit cannot know that your stored function mutates data. Sequences are not transactional in the sense that an increment in a failed transaction still increments the value.

Comment: wow I'm so dumb..  thanks dude..

Answer (score 2):

This particular use case is singled out in ["Understanding Autocommit"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit):

> Full control of the “autocommit” behavior is available using the generative `Connection.execution_options()` method provided on `Connection`, `Engine`, `Executable`, using the “autocommit” flag which will turn on or off the autocommit for the selected scope. For example, a `text()` construct representing a stored procedure that commits might use it so that a SELECT statement will issue a COMMIT:
>
> ```
> engine.execute(text("SELECT my_mutating_procedure()").execution_options(autocommit=True))
> ```

The way SQLAlchemy autocommit detects data changing operations is that it matches the statement against a pattern, looking for things like UPDATE, DELETE, and the like. It is impossible for it to detect if a stored function/procedure performs mutations, and so explicit control over autocommit is provided.

The sequence is incremented even on failure because [`nextval()` and `setval()` calls are never rolled back](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html#id-1.9.3.77.7).