# python sqlalchemy not executing query?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to execute a sql query from a file using sqlalchemy.

When I run the queries, I get a result saying that it affected x amount of rows, but when I check the DB it doesn't actually insert anything to the tables.

Here is my current code:

```
def import_to_db(df, table_name):
    df.to_sql(
        table_name, 
        con=engine, 
        schema='staging', 
        if_exists='replace', 
        index= False, 
        method= 'multi'
    )

    print('imported data to staging.{}'.format(table_name))

    with open('/home/kyle/projects/data_pipelines/ahc/sql/etl_{}.sql'.format(table_name)) as fp:
        etl = fp.read()

    result = engine.execute(etl)
    print('moved {} rows to public.{}'.format(result.rowcount, table_name))
```

When I run the .sql scripts manually, they work fine. I even tried making stored procedures but that didn't work either. Here is an example of one of the sql files im executing:

```
--Delete Id's in prod table that are in current staging table
DELETE
FROM public.table
WHERE key IN
    (SELECT key FROM staging.table);

--Insert new/old id's into prod table and do any cleaning
INSERT INTO 
public.table
SELECT columna, columnb, columnc
FROM staging.table;
```

Comment: Perhaps try `cnxn = engine.raw_connection(); cnxn.autocommit = True; crsr = cnxn.cursor(); crsr.execute(etl)`

Comment: nope. did not work.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561894/calling-stored-function-or-procedure-wont-insert-and-persist-changes

Comment: TL;DR from the dupe target: your SQL file does not begin with something that SQLA recognizes as DDL / DML (instead it begins with a comment), so it does not autocommit.

Comment: Thanks that did it. If you want to type it up as answer ill mark it.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution, although I don't fully understand it.

I added BEGIN; at the top of my script, and COMMIT; at the bottom.

This works, but my row count now say -1 so it doesn't help me much for logging.