# how can i call mysql function using sqlalchemy in python?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, database, sqlalchemy

i'm trying to call a function in mysql from python here is my code
using sqlalchemy

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `my_function`() RETURNS int
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
insert into employeedata (select * from employee where joiningdate <'20160101');


RETURN 1;
END
```

```
engine=sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/sasft')

pd.read_sql_query("select my_function()", engine)
```

tried using MySQL connector as well.

function is getting called through workbench not from python. it doesn't give me any error it's executing but the result is unchanged.

Comment: What do you mean with _the result is unchanged_? Do you get any data? Can you print the following?

`table_df = pd.read_sql_table(table_name, con=engine)`

And then print with
`table_df.head()`

Where `table_name` is any of your MySQL tables?

Comment: @josemrivera i'm not reading a table, calling function which is stored in mysql. from python. employee table records should insert into employee data table after calling the function

Comment: Yep but to test the connection I suggested doing a simple table read. Is the connection working?

Comment: @josemrivera yes it's working  for simple table read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to run a function you don't need to use Pandas SQL interface. You can use the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(text("SELECT my_function()"))
    print(result)
```

Reference: [Understanding Autocommit](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit)

`text()` will then "force" this auto commit.

An alternative would be using a context manager with explicit `autocommit` execution options:

```
with engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True) as connection:
   connection.execute("SELECT my_function()")
```

To test a MWE example using the SQLalchemy connection rather than Pandas API, say that you wanted to read 10 items from a table `table_name`:

```
with engine.connect() as connection:
    rs = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 10")
    for row in rs:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? I just tested (I'll update the answer) and the code is correct.

Comment: no i didn't get any error message. when using ```pd.read_sql_query("select my_function()", engine)```  it's returning 1 as well but in table records are not getting inserted. yes i have tested```with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 10')
    for row in rs:
        print(row)```  it's working

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with the nature of SQLAlchemy's autocommit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565174/2381477

Can you try the alternative I'll post in the answer?

Comment: By using `text()` we might go over the issue of SQLAlchemy not detecting that it has to commit the operation.

Comment: i'm getting this ```NameError: name 'text' is not defined```

Comment: thanks a lot remove text you can update this ```    with engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True) as conn:
        conn.execute("SELECT my_mutating_procedure()")```

Comment: Yeah, that's why I added the `from sqlalchemy import text`. I'll update the answer with the other context manager with `autocommit` option.

Comment: Done, now you have two alternatives, *importing* and using `text()` or with the context manager using the explicit `autocommit` execution option. Hope that helped.