# SQL vs sqlalchemy.execute

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am not sure I understand why SQL code does not have the same behaviour when send using the python library "sqlalchemy" as when executed directly on the database.

#### Establishing connection to MSSQL

```
import sqlalchemy, pyodbc

# Establishing connection
connection_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=' + host + ';Database=' + database + ';UID=' + user + '@' + server_name + ';PWD=' + password + ';Port=' + str(port) + ';'
quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)
db_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))
```

#### Example of expected behaviour

```
# SQL executed in database
CREATE TABLE my_table (col1 float(53), col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(10))

# SQL executed using sqlalchemy engine
db_engine.execute("CREATE TABLE my_table (col1 float(53), col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(10))")
```

Both examples create the table as expected, but when I want to run a more complicated query, things start to go wrong when using sqlalchemy!

#### Unexpected behaviour

```
# SQL executed in database
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from information_schema.tables where table_name='my_table') CREATE TABLE my_table (col1 float(53), col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(10))

# SQL executed using sqlalchemy engine
db_engine.execute("IF NOT EXISTS (select * from information_schema.tables where table_name='my_table') CREATE TABLE my_table (col1 float(53), col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(10))")
```

Here if the table does not exist the table is supposed to be created. This works when the SQL query is executed directly in the database, but using sqlalchemy nothing happens and I don't even get an error message. I don't get why????

Comment: Autocommit does not understand your statement.

Comment: Ok, do you have a suggestion of how to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, got distracted. This is a somewhat common question, you can find explanations for example here (in addition to the dupe target): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376142/teradata-merge-yielding-no-results-when-executed-through-sqlalchemy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561894/calling-stored-function-or-procedure-wont-insert-and-persist-changes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496027/creating-functions-and-triggers-in-postgresql-with-sqlalchemy

Comment: I have read all three posts and the documentation, and I am still not sure I understand the purpose of this behaviour. Why would I not want a SQL statement to be committed automatically? I would expect autocommit=True to be the default behaviour.

Comment: That you'd have to ask from the author(s) of the library, namely zzzeek. It seems they're planning on removing the autocommit feature entirely in SQLA 2.0. My own guess is it's a kind of "safe default", or in other words by default rollback, if unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by turning on autocommit. I am not sure why this convoluted thing works, but it does the trick.

#### Fixing the unexpected behaviour

```
import sqlalchemy
import text from sqlalchemy

# Creating text query with autocommit on
my_query = text("IF NOT EXISTS (select * from information_schema.tables where table_name='my_table') CREATE TABLE my_table (col1 float(53), col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(10))").execution_options(autocommit=True)

# Executing query
db_engine.engine.execute(my_query)
```