# Using python sqlalchemy to execute raw queries with WITH statement

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert values into a Postgres11 database with raw sqlalchemy `text()` queries.
The following SQL query works correctly when I run it through psql-client:

```
WITH a AS (
  INSERT INTO person (id) 
       VALUES ('a')
    RETURNING id
) 
INSERT INTO person_info (person_id) 
     SELECT id 
       FROM a;
```

All rows are correctly inserted:

```
# select id from person;
 id 
----
 a
(1 row)
```

However, if I create an engine in sqlalchemy and call execute on it with an identical query, it runs successfully but no rows are inserted:

```
>>> engine.execute("WITH a AS (INSERT INTO person (id) VALUES ('b') RETURNING id) INSERT INTO person_info (person_id) SELECT id from a")
<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x7f25e6c2a090>
```

But no new row was inserted:

```
# select id from person;
 id 
----
 a
(1 row)
```

In what way is running the query through the psql-client different from executing it through sqlalchemy?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347565/executing-multiple-statements-with-postgresql-via-sqlalchemy-does-not-persist-ch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question got [answered on github](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5090#issuecomment-573368726).

The solution is to wrap the execute in a transaction context:

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
   conn.execute("whatever")
```

Comment: Consider closing the question as answered :-) Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the following code helped me. Without the `conn.execute("COMMIT;")` part, I was not able to see all my changes reflected in my database.

```
with self.engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sql_query)
    conn.execute("COMMIT;")
```