# Insert Data in PostgreSQL with plpgsql functions using sqlAlchemy and python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, plpgsql

I am new to database and sqlAlchemy, it is maybe a simple or stupid question. But I couldn't find any solution.

I have an existing project and I am trying to change the current implementation to use SQLAlchemy.

My problem is that the code is running without errors and I receive a unique job id, which I see in the returned data. But I have no entry in the database.
Because I use connectionless execution, I thougt I can call the function this way.

Existing .sql file:

```
CREATE TYPE job_status_type AS ENUM (
    'SCHEDULED', 'SUCCESS', 'ERROR', 'CANCELLED', 'MISSED'
);

CREATE TABLE job (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES user(id),
    param_id TEXT REFERENCES param(id),
    proc_name TEXT,
    status job_status_type DEFAULT 'SCHEDULED',
    run_date TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT current_timestamp
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_job_run_date() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $check_job_run_date$
BEGIN
    if NEW.run_date < (current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 second') THEN
        RAISE 'job_run_date_in_past';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$check_job_run_date$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER check_job_run_date BEFORE INSERT ON job
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_job_run_date();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_job(INTEGER, TEXT, TEXT, TIMESTAMPTZ) RETURNS SETOF job AS $$
DECLARE
    new_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO job (user_id, param_id, proc_name, run_date) 
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING id INTO new_id;

    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM job WHERE id = new_id;
END;
```

Old implementation, was successfull running:

```
def insert_job(db, user_id: int, param_id: str, proc_name: str, run_date: datetime) -> Job:
    try:
        db.execute('SELECT * FROM add_job(%s, %s, %s, %s)', (user_id, param_id, proc_name, run_date))
    except RaiseException as e:
        raise

    db.commit()
    job = db.fetchone()
    return job
```

New Implementation:

```
def insert_job(db, user_id: int, param_id: str, proc_name: str, run_date: datetime) -> Job:
    query = select([func.add_job(user_id, param_id, proc_name, run_date)])
    try:
        result = engine.execute(query).fetchone()
    except RaiseException as e:
        raise
    return result
```

Comment: SQLA's autocommit does not recognize a SELECT as a data changing operation without some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347565/executing-multiple-statements-with-postgresql-via-sqlalchemy-does-not-persist-ch, but the given answer is even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've used SQLAlchemy, but back in the day you needed to issue a commit for the transaction to be committed on the DB side. It would certainly have the symptom you're seeing if this is the problem. Try changing the new implementation to:

```
def insert_job(db, user_id: int, param_id: str, proc_name: str, run_date: datetime) -> Job:
    query = select([func.add_job(user_id, param_id, proc_name, run_date)])
    with engine.begin() as conn:
        result = conn.execute(query).fetchone()
    return result
```

(the `with` block just establishes a transaction and commits it when the block completes without an exception)